# Fetch strings of date from a given arrays of date in laravel blade file

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I want to extract dates from a a arrays of dates which i was fetching from the database .

```
[
    {"event_start_date":"2019-03-12"},
    {"event_start_date":"2019-07-05"},
    {"event_start_date":"2019-07-05"},
    {"event_start_date":"2019-08-01"}
]
```

i want to fetch those controller datas to .blade.php file in

```
["2019-03-12,2019-03-12,2019-03-12,2019-03-12".split(",")]
```

passing values from controller in `$events`,then

```
input type="text" name="holidayarray" id="holidayarray" value="{{$events}}"
```

i am writing in javascript

```
var event=$('#holidayarray').val();
```

to fetch the data from `$events` then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            document.getElementById("date").value=event;
}
```

then

```
input type="text" name="date" value="" id="date"
```

Comment: write the code you tried to solve your problem

Comment: passing values from controller in $events,then <input type="text" name="holidayarray" id="holidayarray" value="{{$events}}">  i am writing in javascript var event=$('#holidayarray').val(); to fetch the data from $events. then  $(document).ready(function(){

            document.getElementById("date").value=event;
}  then <input type="text" name="date" value="" id="date">

Comment: please edit your answer and write the code

Comment: see the problem now

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not complete and I assume you are trying to get the list of dates and show them as value in the input field.

if `event_start_date` column store the dates of the events. Then you can you can use the following code to get the list of dates.

```php
Event::all()->pluck('event_start_date);
```

Please show the complete code of the controller and the view file you are struggling with.